# Why is my F# function's return type bool?

Tags: reflection, f#

I am writing a function that takes a [PropertyInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.propertyinfo.aspx) object, fetches MyAttribute and returns a MyAttribute object:

```
let getparamattribute(p : PropertyInfo) = 
    let attr = p.GetCustomAttribute (typeof<MyAttribute>, true) 
    attr :? MyAttribute
```

However FSI shows the return type as bool:

```
val getparamattribute : (PropertyInfo -> bool)
```

Why?

Answer (score 6):

That's exactly what `:?` operator does:

> Returns `true` if the value matches the specified type; otherwise,
>   returns `false` (type test operator).

What you're looking for is `:?>` downcast operator:

> The `:?>` operator performs a dynamic cast, which means that the success
>   of the cast is determined at run time. A cast that uses the `:?>`
>   operator is not checked at compile time; but at run time, an attempt
>   is made to cast to the specified type. If the object is compatible
>   with the target type, the cast succeeds. If the object is not
>   compatible with the target type, the runtime raises an
>   `InvalidCastException`.

*from [Symbol and Operator Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233228.aspx)*

Comment: I thought it was the downcast operator ?